# Java OkHttp request cannot be satisfied

Tags: java, authentication, url, httprequest, okhttp

I am using okhttp to download a string from an url. Here is the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     String jsonString = downloadJsonString("https://api.korbit.co.kr/v1/ticker/detailed?currency_pair=btc_krw");
     System.out.println(jsonString);
 }

String downloadJsonString (String url) throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
```

The result is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Request blocked.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: jIs6PvNF01BMsQrynj4pk8eBXuQW-n-Q02Tav0SQghSZ7TzZOFfrAg==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

If I put the url into browsers, it works fine. Here is the response:

```
{"timestamp":1507942765556,"last":"6355000","bid":"6355000","ask":"6358500","low":"6310000","high":"6949000","volume":"12329.815314799943534093","change":"0","changePercent":"0"}
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 2):

The response you are getting is Korbit's `403 Forbidden` response. You are getting this response because the Korbit API requires you to provide some authentication details. From [the docs](https://apidocs.korbit.co.kr/#authentication):

> Prior to using Korbit API, you need to authenticate a user. As Korbit API provides OAuth 2.0 interface, you get an access token after a successful authentication. For each API request, you need to set Authorization HTTP header with the access token.
>   API Keys and Secrets
>
> You need to request an API key and secret to use Korbit API. All Korbit users can get the API key through the Korbit website. You can sign in into your Korbit account by direct authentication API call, which requires username and password in the body of the POST request to get an access token (and a refresh token). In this document,  denotes an API key, and  denotes a corresponding API secret.

So, you register with Korbit, they provide you with some authentication details and then you include those details in your HTTP requests.

You stated that the **same** call completes via your browser, this must be because Korbit allow unauthenticated calls which originate from a browser (rather than a programmatic HTTP client). To prove this just trace the call from your browser and you'll find that the request contains a header named "User-Agent" with [one of these values](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

You *could* mimic this in your code as follows:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:51.0)")
        .build();
```

This would allow your call to complete successfully but it is not recommended and I suspect Korbit would disallow it after a limited number of tries. Instead, you need to follow [Korbit's instructions](https://apidocs.korbit.co.kr/#authentication) and register yourelf and then provide your authentication details in your request headers.

Comment: THANK YOU. I cannot believe they require a user agent.